# How to make angular-cli not to generate js-files?

Tags: angular

In one of my projects **angular-cli** creates *.js files as well as *.ts ones  when I generate something (ng g ...).

But in the other project **angular-cli** creates just *.ts files.

I compared ***angular-cli.json*** files in both projects - they are similar.

Q: How can I make angular-cli not to generate js-files?

Comment: sounds to me that you have a typescript compiler running in one of your projects inside your `IDE`. Are you using intellij/webstorm?

Comment: can you be more specific about what js & ts files you're referring to, and what commands result in ts/js?

Comment: Compare tsconfig.json files also

Comment: @PierreDuc I closed all `IDE`s , typescript is not running ..

Comment: @Newbie well, for instance, I run this comand `ng g s my-service` and in 1st projects folder I get 2 files `my-service.service.ts, my-service.service.spec.ts` and in the other projects folder I get 4 files : `my-service.service.js, my-service.service.spec.js, my-service.service.ts, my-service.service.spec.ts`

Comment: @DDRamone `tsconfig.json` files are absolutely similar

Comment: @Zurab-D I think the versions of angular could be different? is one of them an old project and the other new? try to check them out...? also try creating a new project and test it out

Comment: @Newbie Yeah thats right :)) The newer version generates *.js files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Zurab-D yeah i guessed so, there is always a difference in generated files depending on the version. should i post it as an answer?

Comment: @Newbie yes, sure, post it as an answer. thanks

Comment: I had this EXACT SAME ISSUE. I had to delete and reinstall my node modules to get this over this issue. Nothing else worked. It is a simple enough fix.